# Regex: Filter special characters (like Japanese) but preserve Emojis

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a regex `/[^\x00-\x7F]/g`, which detects any special characters like Japanese characters, but this regex also filters out emojis, and I was wondering how I could add something to this regex that would make it not detect them. This is the regex that DOES detect emojis, is there a way to 'invert' it? `(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])`

Comment: Use the pattern in `.replace`  to  remove emojis. What is your use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easier said than done.

First, the regex `(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])` may [capture all emojis](https://www.regextester.com/106421) but it also captures Japanese characters (and other stuff) you want to filter ([try it](https://regex101.com/r/yrjpej/2/), have you!). So, the suggested pattern is not really helpful.
I searched a bit and decided to use Mathias Bynens' [emoji-regex](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/emoji-regex) definition instead (see: [text.js](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/emoji-regex/blob/master/text.js) or [index.js](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/emoji-regex/blob/master/index.js) depending on your environment) - which seems to be more narrow/precise but less concise ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/MhWKyw/1)).

Second, usually, one would use a negative lookahead to remove the emojis from the filter range as a workaround for engines like EcmaScript/JS's that do not support character class subtraction.
However, this does not work well (even if the regex engine at hand would support subtractions) since we already have a negated character set and negation takes precedence over subtraction (see: [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclasssubtract.html)). So I have to use (another) trick: [Deleting the Matches](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#deletevariation) `(KeepThis)|DeleteThis`

[Simple Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eG3Zpx/1), [Full Emoji Set Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ed2dOy/1)

```js
const regex = /(\uD83C\uDFF4\uDB40\uDC67\uDB40\uDC62(?:\uDB40\uDC77\uDB40\uDC6C\uDB40\uDC73|\uDB40\uDC73\uDB40\uDC63\uDB40\uDC74|\uDB40\uDC65\uDB40\uDC6E\uDB40\uDC67)\uDB40\uDC7F|(?:\uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C\uDFFB\u200D\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D\uD83E\uDDD1|\uD83D\uDC69\uD83C\uDFFC\u200D\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC69)\uD83C\uDFFB|\uD83D\uDC68(?:\uD83C\uDFFC\u200D(?:\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC68\uD83C\uDFFB|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\uD83C\uDFFF\u200D(?:\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC68(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFE])|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\uD83C\uDFFE\u200D(?:\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC68(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFD])|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\uD83C\uDFFD\u200D(?:\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC68(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB\uDFFC])|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\u200D(?:\u2764\uFE0F\u200D(?:\uD83D\uDC8B\u200D)?\uD83D\uDC68|(?:\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69])\u200D(?:\uD83D\uDC66\u200D\uD83D\uDC66|\uD83D\uDC67\u200D(?:\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67]))|\uD83D\uDC66\u200D\uD83D\uDC66|\uD83D\uDC67\u200D(?:\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67])|(?:\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69])\u200D(?:\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67])|[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F|\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67]|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|(?:\uD83C\uDFFB\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708]|\uD83C\uDFFF\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708]|\uD83C\uDFFE\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708]|\uD83C\uDFFD\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708]|\uD83C\uDFFC\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708])\uFE0F|\uD83C\uDFFB\u200D(?:\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])|\uD83E\uDDD1(?:\uD83C\uDFFF\u200D\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D\uD83E\uDDD1(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])|\u200D\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D\uD83E\uDDD1)|\uD83D\uDC69(?:\uD83C\uDFFE\u200D(?:\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC68(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFD\uDFFF])|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\uD83C\uDFFD\u200D(?:\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC68(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB\uDFFC\uDFFE\uDFFF])|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\uD83C\uDFFC\u200D(?:\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC68(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB\uDFFD-\uDFFF])|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\uD83C\uDFFB\u200D(?:\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC68(?:\uD83C[\uDFFC-\uDFFF])|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\u200D(?:\u2764\uFE0F\u200D(?:\uD83D\uDC8B\u200D(?:\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69])|\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69])|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\uD83C\uDFFF\u200D(?:\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD]))|(?:\uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C\uDFFE\u200D\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D\uD83E\uDDD1|\uD83D\uDC69\uD83C\uDFFF\u200D\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D(?:\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69]))(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFE])|(?:\uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C\uDFFD\u200D\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D\uD83E\uDDD1|\uD83D\uDC69\uD83C\uDFFE\u200D\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC69)(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFD])|(?:\uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C\uDFFC\u200D\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D\uD83E\uDDD1|\uD83D\uDC69\uD83C\uDFFD\u200D\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC69)(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB\uDFFC])|\uD83D\uDC69\u200D\uD83D\uDC69\u200D(?:\uD83D\uDC66\u200D\uD83D\uDC66|\uD83D\uDC67\u200D(?:\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67]))|\uD83D\uDC69\u200D\uD83D\uDC66\u200D\uD83D\uDC66|\uD83D\uDC69\u200D\uD83D\uDC69\u200D(?:\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67])|(?:\uD83D\uDC41\uFE0F\u200D\uD83D\uDDE8|\uD83D\uDC69(?:\uD83C\uDFFF\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708]|\uD83C\uDFFE\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708]|\uD83C\uDFFD\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708]|\uD83C\uDFFC\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708]|\uD83C\uDFFB\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708]|\u200D[\u2695\u2696\u2708])|(?:\uD83C[\uDFC3\uDFC4\uDFCA]|\uD83D[\uDC6E\uDC71\uDC73\uDC77\uDC81\uDC82\uDC86\uDC87\uDE45-\uDE47\uDE4B\uDE4D\uDE4E\uDEA3\uDEB4-\uDEB6]|\uD83E[\uDD26\uDD37-\uDD39\uDD3D\uDD3E\uDDB8\uDDB9\uDDCD-\uDDCF\uDDD6-\uDDDD])(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])\u200D[\u2640\u2642]|(?:\u26F9|\uD83C[\uDFCB\uDFCC]|\uD83D\uDD75)(?:\uFE0F\u200D[\u2640\u2642]|(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])\u200D[\u2640\u2642])|\uD83C\uDFF4\u200D\u2620|(?:\uD83C[\uDFC3\uDFC4\uDFCA]|\uD83D[\uDC6E\uDC6F\uDC71\uDC73\uDC77\uDC81\uDC82\uDC86\uDC87\uDE45-\uDE47\uDE4B\uDE4D\uDE4E\uDEA3\uDEB4-\uDEB6]|\uD83E[\uDD26\uDD37-\uDD39\uDD3C-\uDD3E\uDDB8\uDDB9\uDDCD-\uDDCF\uDDD6-\uDDDF])\u200D[\u2640\u2642])\uFE0F|\uD83D\uDC69\u200D\uD83D\uDC67\u200D(?:\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67])|\uD83C\uDFF3\uFE0F\u200D\uD83C\uDF08|\uD83D\uDC69\u200D\uD83D\uDC67|\uD83D\uDC69\u200D\uD83D\uDC66|\uD83D\uDC15\u200D\uD83E\uDDBA|\uD83C\uDDFD\uD83C\uDDF0|\uD83C\uDDF6\uD83C\uDDE6|\uD83C\uDDF4\uD83C\uDDF2|\uD83E\uDDD1(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])|\uD83D\uDC69(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])|\uD83C\uDDFF(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDF2\uDDFC])|\uD83C\uDDFE(?:\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDF9])|\uD83C\uDDFC(?:\uD83C[\uDDEB\uDDF8])|\uD83C\uDDFB(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDEA\uDDEC\uDDEE\uDDF3\uDDFA])|\uD83C\uDDFA(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDEC\uDDF2\uDDF3\uDDF8\uDDFE\uDDFF])|\uD83C\uDDF9(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDE9\uDDEB-\uDDED\uDDEF-\uDDF4\uDDF7\uDDF9\uDDFB\uDDFC\uDDFF])|\uD83C\uDDF8(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6-\uDDEA\uDDEC-\uDDF4\uDDF7-\uDDF9\uDDFB\uDDFD-\uDDFF])|\uD83C\uDDF7(?:\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDF4\uDDF8\uDDFA\uDDFC])|\uD83C\uDDF5(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDEA-\uDDED\uDDF0-\uDDF3\uDDF7-\uDDF9\uDDFC\uDDFE])|\uD83C\uDDF3(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDEA-\uDDEC\uDDEE\uDDF1\uDDF4\uDDF5\uDDF7\uDDFA\uDDFF])|\uD83C\uDDF2(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8-\uDDED\uDDF0-\uDDFF])|\uD83C\uDDF1(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6-\uDDE8\uDDEE\uDDF0\uDDF7-\uDDFB\uDDFE])|\uD83C\uDDF0(?:\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDEC-\uDDEE\uDDF2\uDDF3\uDDF5\uDDF7\uDDFC\uDDFE\uDDFF])|\uD83C\uDDEF(?:\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDF5])|\uD83C\uDDEE(?:\uD83C[\uDDE8-\uDDEA\uDDF1-\uDDF4\uDDF6-\uDDF9])|\uD83C\uDDED(?:\uD83C[\uDDF0\uDDF2\uDDF3\uDDF7\uDDF9\uDDFA])|\uD83C\uDDEC(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE7\uDDE9-\uDDEE\uDDF1-\uDDF3\uDDF5-\uDDFA\uDDFC\uDDFE])|\uD83C\uDDEB(?:\uD83C[\uDDEE-\uDDF0\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDF7])|\uD83C\uDDEA(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDEA\uDDEC\uDDED\uDDF7-\uDDFA])|\uD83C\uDDE9(?:\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDEC\uDDEF\uDDF0\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDFF])|\uD83C\uDDE8(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDE9\uDDEB-\uDDEE\uDDF0-\uDDF5\uDDF7\uDDFA-\uDDFF])|\uD83C\uDDE7(?:\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE7\uDDE9-\uDDEF\uDDF1-\uDDF4\uDDF6-\uDDF9\uDDFB\uDDFC\uDDFE\uDDFF])|\uD83C\uDDE6(?:\uD83C[\uDDE8-\uDDEC\uDDEE\uDDF1\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDF6-\uDDFA\uDDFC\uDDFD\uDDFF])|[#\*0-9]\uFE0F\u20E3|(?:\uD83C[\uDFC3\uDFC4\uDFCA]|\uD83D[\uDC6E\uDC71\uDC73\uDC77\uDC81\uDC82\uDC86\uDC87\uDE45-\uDE47\uDE4B\uDE4D\uDE4E\uDEA3\uDEB4-\uDEB6]|\uD83E[\uDD26\uDD37-\uDD39\uDD3D\uDD3E\uDDB8\uDDB9\uDDCD-\uDDCF\uDDD6-\uDDDD])(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])|(?:\u26F9|\uD83C[\uDFCB\uDFCC]|\uD83D\uDD75)(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])|(?:[\u261D\u270A-\u270D]|\uD83C[\uDF85\uDFC2\uDFC7]|\uD83D[\uDC42\uDC43\uDC46-\uDC50\uDC66\uDC67\uDC6B-\uDC6D\uDC70\uDC72\uDC74-\uDC76\uDC78\uDC7C\uDC83\uDC85\uDCAA\uDD74\uDD7A\uDD90\uDD95\uDD96\uDE4C\uDE4F\uDEC0\uDECC]|\uD83E[\uDD0F\uDD18-\uDD1C\uDD1E\uDD1F\uDD30-\uDD36\uDDB5\uDDB6\uDDBB\uDDD2-\uDDD5])(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])|(?:[\u231A\u231B\u23E9-\u23EC\u23F0\u23F3\u25FD\u25FE\u2614\u2615\u2648-\u2653\u267F\u2693\u26A1\u26AA\u26AB\u26BD\u26BE\u26C4\u26C5\u26CE\u26D4\u26EA\u26F2\u26F3\u26F5\u26FA\u26FD\u2705\u270A\u270B\u2728\u274C\u274E\u2753-\u2755\u2757\u2795-\u2797\u27B0\u27BF\u2B1B\u2B1C\u2B50\u2B55]|\uD83C[\uDC04\uDCCF\uDD8E\uDD91-\uDD9A\uDDE6-\uDDFF\uDE01\uDE1A\uDE2F\uDE32-\uDE36\uDE38-\uDE3A\uDE50\uDE51\uDF00-\uDF20\uDF2D-\uDF35\uDF37-\uDF7C\uDF7E-\uDF93\uDFA0-\uDFCA\uDFCF-\uDFD3\uDFE0-\uDFF0\uDFF4\uDFF8-\uDFFF]|\uD83D[\uDC00-\uDC3E\uDC40\uDC42-\uDCFC\uDCFF-\uDD3D\uDD4B-\uDD4E\uDD50-\uDD67\uDD7A\uDD95\uDD96\uDDA4\uDDFB-\uDE4F\uDE80-\uDEC5\uDECC\uDED0-\uDED2\uDED5\uDEEB\uDEEC\uDEF4-\uDEFA\uDFE0-\uDFEB]|\uD83E[\uDD0D-\uDD3A\uDD3C-\uDD45\uDD47-\uDD71\uDD73-\uDD76\uDD7A-\uDDA2\uDDA5-\uDDAA\uDDAE-\uDDCA\uDDCD-\uDDFF\uDE70-\uDE73\uDE78-\uDE7A\uDE80-\uDE82\uDE90-\uDE95])|(?:[#\*0-9\xA9\xAE\u203C\u2049\u2122\u2139\u2194-\u2199\u21A9\u21AA\u231A\u231B\u2328\u23CF\u23E9-\u23F3\u23F8-\u23FA\u24C2\u25AA\u25AB\u25B6\u25C0\u25FB-\u25FE\u2600-\u2604\u260E\u2611\u2614\u2615\u2618\u261D\u2620\u2622\u2623\u2626\u262A\u262E\u262F\u2638-\u263A\u2640\u2642\u2648-\u2653\u265F\u2660\u2663\u2665\u2666\u2668\u267B\u267E\u267F\u2692-\u2697\u2699\u269B\u269C\u26A0\u26A1\u26AA\u26AB\u26B0\u26B1\u26BD\u26BE\u26C4\u26C5\u26C8\u26CE\u26CF\u26D1\u26D3\u26D4\u26E9\u26EA\u26F0-\u26F5\u26F7-\u26FA\u26FD\u2702\u2705\u2708-\u270D\u270F\u2712\u2714\u2716\u271D\u2721\u2728\u2733\u2734\u2744\u2747\u274C\u274E\u2753-\u2755\u2757\u2763\u2764\u2795-\u2797\u27A1\u27B0\u27BF\u2934\u2935\u2B05-\u2B07\u2B1B\u2B1C\u2B50\u2B55\u3030\u303D\u3297\u3299]|\uD83C[\uDC04\uDCCF\uDD70\uDD71\uDD7E\uDD7F\uDD8E\uDD91-\uDD9A\uDDE6-\uDDFF\uDE01\uDE02\uDE1A\uDE2F\uDE32-\uDE3A\uDE50\uDE51\uDF00-\uDF21\uDF24-\uDF93\uDF96\uDF97\uDF99-\uDF9B\uDF9E-\uDFF0\uDFF3-\uDFF5\uDFF7-\uDFFF]|\uD83D[\uDC00-\uDCFD\uDCFF-\uDD3D\uDD49-\uDD4E\uDD50-\uDD67\uDD6F\uDD70\uDD73-\uDD7A\uDD87\uDD8A-\uDD8D\uDD90\uDD95\uDD96\uDDA4\uDDA5\uDDA8\uDDB1\uDDB2\uDDBC\uDDC2-\uDDC4\uDDD1-\uDDD3\uDDDC-\uDDDE\uDDE1\uDDE3\uDDE8\uDDEF\uDDF3\uDDFA-\uDE4F\uDE80-\uDEC5\uDECB-\uDED2\uDED5\uDEE0-\uDEE5\uDEE9\uDEEB\uDEEC\uDEF0\uDEF3-\uDEFA\uDFE0-\uDFEB]|\uD83E[\uDD0D-\uDD3A\uDD3C-\uDD45\uDD47-\uDD71\uDD73-\uDD76\uDD7A-\uDDA2\uDDA5-\uDDAA\uDDAE-\uDDCA\uDDCD-\uDDFF\uDE70-\uDE73\uDE78-\uDE7A\uDE80-\uDE82\uDE90-\uDE95])\uFE0F?|(?:[\u261D\u26F9\u270A-\u270D]|\uD83C[\uDF85\uDFC2-\uDFC4\uDFC7\uDFCA-\uDFCC]|\uD83D[\uDC42\uDC43\uDC46-\uDC50\uDC66-\uDC78\uDC7C\uDC81-\uDC83\uDC85-\uDC87\uDC8F\uDC91\uDCAA\uDD74\uDD75\uDD7A\uDD90\uDD95\uDD96\uDE45-\uDE47\uDE4B-\uDE4F\uDEA3\uDEB4-\uDEB6\uDEC0\uDECC]|\uD83E[\uDD0F\uDD18-\uDD1F\uDD26\uDD30-\uDD39\uDD3C-\uDD3E\uDDB5\uDDB6\uDDB8\uDDB9\uDDBB\uDDCD-\uDDCF\uDDD1-\uDDDD]))|[^\x00-\x7F]/g;
const str = `                  ☺️                               ☹️                                                          
People and Fantasy
           ‍♀️ ‍♂️   ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ️‍♀️ ️‍♂️ ‍⚕️ ‍⚕️ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍✈️ ‍✈️ ‍ ‍ ‍⚖️ ‍⚖️       ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️    ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️     ‍♀️ ‍♂️  ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️     ‍❤️‍ ‍❤️‍  ‍❤️‍‍ ‍❤️‍‍  ‍‍ ‍‍‍ ‍‍‍ ‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍ ‍‍‍ ‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍ ‍‍‍ ‍‍‍ ‍ ‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍ ‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍         ✊    ✌️        ☝️ ✋          ✍️                 
Clothing and Accessories
                      ⛑             
Pale Emojis
     ‍♀️     ‍♀️  ‍♀️  ‍♀️  ‍♀️  ‍♀️  ‍⚕️ ‍⚕️ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍✈️ ‍✈️ ‍ ‍ ‍⚖️ ‍⚖️         ‍♀️   ‍♂️  ‍♂️  ‍♂️  ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️  ‍♂️  ‍♂️  ‍♂️  ‍♂️    ‍♀️  ‍♀️          ✊    ✌        ☝ ✋        ✍    
Cream White Emojis
     ‍♀️     ‍♀️  ‍♀️  ‍♀️  ‍♀️  ‍♀️  ‍⚕️ ‍⚕️ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍✈️ ‍✈️ ‍ ‍ ‍⚖️ ‍⚖️         ‍♀️   ‍♂️  ‍♂️  ‍♂️  ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️  ‍♂️  ‍♂️  ‍♂️  ‍♂️    ‍♀️  ‍♀️          ✊    ✌        ☝ ✋        ✍    
Moderate Brown Emojis
     ‍♀️     ‍♀️  ‍♀️  ‍♀️  ‍♀️  ‍♀️  ‍⚕️ ‍⚕️ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍✈️ ‍✈️ ‍ ‍ ‍⚖️ ‍⚖️         ‍♀️   ‍♂️  ‍♂️  ‍♂️  ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️  ‍♂️  ‍♂️  ‍♂️  ‍♂️    ‍♀️  ‍♀️          ✊    ✌        ☝ ✋        ✍    
Dark Brown Emojis
     ‍♀️     ‍♀️  ‍♀️  ‍♀️  ‍♀️  ‍♀️  ‍⚕️ ‍⚕️ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍✈️ ‍✈️ ‍ ‍ ‍⚖️ ‍⚖️         ‍♀️   ‍♂️  ‍♂️  ‍♂️  ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️  ‍♂️  ‍♂️  ‍♂️  ‍♂️    ‍♀️  ‍♀️          ✊    ✌        ☝ ✋        ✍    
Black Emojis
     ‍♀️     ‍♀️  ‍♀️  ‍♀️  ‍♀️  ‍♀️  ‍⚕️ ‍⚕️ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍✈️ ‍✈️ ‍ ‍ ‍⚖️ ‍⚖️         ‍♀️   ‍♂️  ‍♂️  ‍♂️  ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️  ‍♂️  ‍♂️  ‍♂️  ‍♂️    ‍♀️  ‍♀️          ✊    ✌        ☝ ✋        ✍    
Animals & Nature
 
                                                                                                               ☘️                                   ⭐️  ✨ ⚡️ ☄️     ☀️  ⛅️  ☁️   ⛈   ❄️ ☃️ ⛄️     ☔️ ☂️  
Food & Drink
 
                                                                                      ☕️                 
Activity and Sports
 
⚽️   ⚾️              ⛳️      ⛸     ⛷  ️‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ️‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ⛹️‍♀️ ⛹‍♀️ ⛹‍♀️ ⛹‍♀️ ⛹‍♀️ ⛹‍♀️ ⛹️‍♂️ ⛹‍♂️ ⛹‍♂️ ⛹‍♂️ ⛹‍♂️ ⛹‍♂️  ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ️‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ️‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️       ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️            ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♀️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️               ♟    
Travel & Places
 
                                     ✈️          ⛵️    ⛴  ⚓️ ⛽️               ⛲️ ⛱     ⛰    ⛺️                   ⛪️    ⛩                 
Objects
 
 Try Audible today to get  two free Audiobooks of your choice.

⌚️    ⌨️                   ☎️        ⏱ ⏲ ⏰  ⌛️ ⏳                  ⚖️   ⚒  ⛏  ⚙️ ⛓     ⚔️   ⚰️ ⚱️         ⚗️                                                      ✉️                                                     ✂️   ✒️    ✏️      
Symbols
 
❤️        ❣️         ☮️ ✝️ ☪️  ☸️ ✡️   ☯️ ☦️  ⛎ ♈️ ♉️ ♊️ ♋️ ♌️ ♍️ ♎️ ♏️ ♐️ ♑️ ♒️ ♓️  ⚛️  ☢️ ☣️    ️   ️ ✴️    ㊙️ ㊗️     ️ ️   ️  ❌ ⭕️  ⛔️     ♨️        ❗️ ❕ ❓ ❔ ‼️ ⁉️   〽️ ⚠️   ⚜️  ♻️ ✅ ️  ❇️ ✳️ ❎   Ⓜ️     ♿️ ️  ️              ℹ️          0️⃣ 1️⃣ 2️⃣ 3️⃣ 4️⃣ 5️⃣ 6️⃣ 7️⃣ 8️⃣ 9️⃣   #️⃣ *️⃣ ⏏️ ▶️ ⏸ ⏯ ⏹ ⏺ ⏭ ⏮ ⏩ ⏪ ⏫ ⏬ ◀️   ➡️ ⬅️ ⬆️ ⬇️ ↗️ ↘️ ↙️ ↖️ ↕️ ↔️ ↪️ ↩️ ⤴️ ⤵️        ➕ ➖ ➗ ✖️ ♾   ™️ ©️ ®️ 〰️ ➰ ➿      ✔️ ☑️  ⚪️ ⚫️           ▪️ ▫️ ◾️ ◽️ ◼️ ◻️ ⬛️ ⬜️         ‍    ♠️ ♣️ ♥️ ♦️   ️                        
Flags
 
All flag emojis for every country.

️    ️‍ ‍☠️                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 People •  Animals •  Food • ⚽️ Activities •  Travel •  Objects •  Symbols • ️‍ Flags

New Emojis

      ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍ ‍  ‍♀️ ‍♂️  ‍♀️ ‍♂️                                      ♟                  ♾ ‍☠️

Counter example: カタカナ`;
const subst = `$1`;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

As you can see, the Japanese characters are gone but the Emojis are preserved.

Comment: This is great, thanks for taking the time to explain this to me.

Comment: @wp78de great example! I just improved the end of regexp [^\x00-\u024F] so I can match all Latin (from basic to Extended-B. In my case it worked very well!

Comment: @JulioVedovatto welcomed. Yea, I could imagine others want to filter like that as well.